# Can't track down 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller hat is already being presented by

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am experiencing the following error in my SwiftUI-App:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x13000c800> that is already being presented by <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_: 0x130822e00>.'

The error occurs, when coming back to the App from a deep link. After analyzing the deep link in appMain:App I trigger a notification by

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: token.notify), object: nil, userInfo: ["token":token.token]))
```

This notification is processed in my MainTabView

```
.onReceive(pubTokenReceived, perform: { notification in
                timer?.invalidate()
                if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                    receivedToken = userInfo["token"] as! String
                    print (receivedToken)
                        if (token == receivedToken) {
                            let tan = Slt.get6DigitRandomNumberString()

                            print ("TAN: " + tan)
                            slt.sendSMSforIdentificationTo(email: email, tan: tan)
                            firstResponder = .tan
                            timeOrTryCounter = 3
                            sheetId = MainTabViewSheetId(id: .identificationStep2)
                    }
                }
            })
```

This works until the "sheetId" is set. This triggers an update of the sheet, which is shown modally, as "sheetId" is a @State-Varaible of the underlying MainTabView:

@State var sheetId: MainTabViewSheetId?

I can't figure what ultimately triggers the given error. Any ideas? Thank you su much!

Comment: You could try to use 2 sheetId in your case. One for the one started by the app and one when started by the deep link. So you could be sure that only one can be active at the same time.